# MySQL stored proc - Processing millions of records - how to speed up

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, database-performance

I have a stored procedure (provided below) that I wrote to process approx 25 million records.  What this stored procedure is doing is taking a given lat & lon, a distance (25 miles), and the number of records to assign (12), find all records that are in the given boundaries based on the 25 miles, and assign up to 12 records to a user that does not already have records.  And, the user can only have one record per category (so 12 records each with a distinct category).

The stored procedure works great.  The only issue is it is taking a long time.  I create 8 total procs, each identical except for the working table (POSTSINAREATBL[1-8]) so I can speed the process along.  I've had the scripts running for 4 days now and have only processed 3.5 million of the 25 million records.

I'm hoping someone might have some insight and help into how to speed this along.  I really need to get all the records processed within the next 1-2 days and at the rate it's going now, it's going to take almost a month!

Also, with the 8 scripts running, I have the CPU running at 99.8%, so I'm at max capacity.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_pins_in_boundaries`(IN mylon double, IN mylat double, IN dist int, IN numrecords int)
BEGIN
    declare isDone INT;

    declare lat float;
    declare lng float;

    declare lon1 float;
    declare lon2 float; 
    declare lat1 float;
    declare lat2 float;

    declare this_iter_pin_id int;
    declare  use_this_user_id int;

    DECLARE num_results_in_area int;

    DECLARE cur_posts_to_assign_to_user CURSOR FOR select pin_id from POSTSINAREATBL group by category_id limit numrecords;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET isDone = 1;

    IF mylon = 0.000000 OR mylat = 0.000000 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('complete') AS results;
    ELSE

        SET lat=mylon;
        SET lng=mylat;

        -- calculate lon and lat for the rectangle:
        set lon1 = mylon-dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69); 
        set lon2 = mylon+dist/abs(cos(radians(mylat))*69); 
        set lat1 = mylat-(dist/69);  set lat2 = mylat+(dist/69);

        -- calculate lon and lat for the rectangle:
        set lon1 = lng - dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * 111.04);
        set lon2 = lng + dist / ABS(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * 111.04);
        set lat1 = lat - dist / (111.04);
        set lat2 = lat + dist / (111.04);

        -- create temp table and store records matching criteria into table
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS POSTSINAREATBL(
            pin_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
            category_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
            distance DECIMAL(6,1)
        );

        INSERT INTO POSTSINAREATBL (
            SELECT pin_id,category_id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(lng) ) + sin( radians(lat) ) * sin(radians(latitude)) ) ) as distance
            FROM skoovy_prd.pins
            WHERE longitude between lon1 and lon2 
            and latitude between lat1 and lat2 
            and user_id =0
        );

        select count(*) INTO num_results_in_area from POSTSINAREATBL;

        WHILE num_results_in_area > 0 DO

            SET use_this_user_id = (SELECT user_id from skoovy_prd.users WHERE user_id NOT IN(select user_id from skoovy_prd.posts_users_processed) LIMIT 1);

            INSERT INTO skoovy_prd.posts_users_processed (user_id) VALUES(use_this_user_id);

            SET isDone = 0;
            OPEN cur_posts_to_assign_to_user;
            REPEAT
                FETCH cur_posts_to_assign_to_user INTO this_iter_pin_id;

                UPDATE skoovy_prd.pins SET pins.user_id = use_this_user_id WHERE pins.pin_id = this_iter_pin_id;

                DELETE FROM POSTSINAREATBL WHERE pin_id = this_iter_pin_id;

                SET num_results_in_area = num_results_in_area - 1;

            UNTIL isDone END REPEAT;

            CLOSE cur_posts_to_assign_to_user;

        END WHILE;

        TRUNCATE TABLE POSTSINAREATBL;

        SELECT CONCAT('complete') AS results;

    END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enforce **spartial index**? I didn't try it on mysql, but for postgresql there is a **postgis extension**, which provides full set of usefull functions for that kind of tasks. It realy helps me in aproximate the same task.
http://postgis.net/

Check this one http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: Thanks.  I've run some tests and it doesn't appear the performance "issue" is within the query for data within the geolocation ranges.

Comment: If you want to find a bottleneck of your stored procedure run "explain" for every query in your procedure. After you find the problem - just optimize it by using indexes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: Done already.  It's not that there's missing indexes, indexes not being used properly, etc.  It's that there are millions of records and I'm trying to see if maybe there's a more efficient way to do this and to rapidly perform the actions that the proc is currently performing.